# Laplace transform of 1

Tags: laplace-transform

I am getting a little confused when using the Laplace Transform.
So, taking the laplace transform of 1 we get:

$\mathfrak L[1](p)= \int_0^\infty e^{-pt}dt=[-\frac1pe^{-pt}]_0^\infty=\frac1p$ when $\mathfrak R\mathfrak e[p]>0$

So what I am not understanding is the fact that we are not taking into account the imaginary component of p, and so if the real component of p is positive but the imaginary component is negative, won't the $e^{-pt}$ term not vanish to zero as t approaches $\infty$?

Comment: For complex $p=a+bi$ just write $e^{-pt}=e^{-at}e^{-ibt}$. The first term requires $a=\Re{p}>0$ (otherwise the integral diverges). The second term is oscillatory and doesn't cause problem with integration. $e^{-pt}$ therefore goes to zero with $t\to\infty$ for $\Re{p}>0$ and the value of the Laplace transform is $1/p$ (indefinite integral evaluated at the lower bound).

Comment: Ah of course! Thankyou!